# how to sort an array of objects using the value of the objects two times consecutively

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects. Each object has associated with it two fitness values. I want to sort the array first using one fitness value and then do some calculation. And then sort it again using the other fitness value field. I tried to use `compareTo()` method but I could sort it using only one field.

Comment: you need to use 2 different custom-comparators.

Comment: Design your comparator to dynamically take property on the basis of which you want to perform comparison.

Comment: You want 2 different sorted lists? Or you want to sort by one criterion and use a second criterion for sorting objects that are equivalent according to the first criterion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: Use Google Guava and do composite sort

```
new Ordering<X>() {
  public int compare(X x1, X x2) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
      .compare(x1.stringValue, x2.stringValue)
      .compare(x2.dateValue, x1.dateValue) // flipped for reverse order
      .result();
  }
}.immutableSortedCopy(listOfXs);
```

**in between the two compares you can call another method to do your calculation.**

I will suggest use a Mutator

```
interface Mutation<T> {
    void apply(T subject);
}

    <T> Collection<? extends T> mutate(Collection<? extends T> input, Mutation<? super T> mutation) {
        for (T element : input) {
            mutation.apply(element);
        }
        return input;
    }
```